# Add log files to Console.app

Tags: macos, mamp, logging, console.app

I'd like to select [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) logs (in /Applications/MAMP/logs/) from Console.app's "Log List".

Is there a way to add arbitrary log files to Console.app's "Log List"?

Maybe there's a .plist I can edit somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A previous discussion at SO suggests that [symlinking the log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145354/adding-custom-log-locations-to-the-os-x-console-application/523000#523000) into an already recognized directory should work.